# conversion of any date to datetime in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, type-conversion

I want to define a function that takes in a pandas dateframe and iterates through its columns to find if there is any date field or a timestamp which can be an object. I want to convert those fields to DateTime. In short, I want to clean my different dataframes which can come from different sources and have different timestamps and store them. can you guys point me in the right direction?

```
def dateConversion(flattenedObject):
    for col in df.columns:
        df[col]=pd.to_datetime(df[col])
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what the problem is with your code, why your function has an argument it doesn't use, and why your function doesn't return anything. Maybe you could add more detail to flesh out the problem

Answer (score 0):

something like this.. ?

```
def test_datetime(dataframe):
    for col in dataframe.select_dtypes('object').columns:
        try:
            dataframe[col] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe[col])
            print(f'Converted {col}')
        except ValueError:
            print(f"{col} does not conform to standard datetime format")
```

## Test

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date_test' : ['01-01-2020'],
                  'string_test' : ['not a date']})

print(test_datetime(df))
Converted date_test
string_test does not conform to standard datetime format

print(df.dtypes)

date_test      datetime64[ns]
string_test            object
dtype: object
```